# Is saying 'I wouldn't delude yourself...' correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

The following is a line from the TV show Arrow:

> "Nanda Parbat is remote, but **I wouldn't delude yourself into thinking**
>   that Ra's-Al-Ghul missed your televised return to Starling City"

*From Season 3, Episode 13*

Now, I've come across the `I wouldn't` construct many times. Instead of `You shouldn't do that`, people say `I wouldn't do that`. I've always thought they meant `I wouldn't do that if I were you`, and dropped the `if I were you` part.

But shouldn't the 'I' analogy be consistent? Shouldn't the line be `I wouldn't delude MYSELF into thinking... (if I were you)`? Or am I missing something here? Any thoughts on the correct usage of the `I wouldn't` construct?

Comment: In a strict, grammatical sense, you are correct in that it doesn't make sense. However as a verbal construction, it sounds idiomatic to my (British English) ear and the intended meaning seems clear enough.

Comment: I strongly suspect the *would*  there in that sentence is used in a different sense, though in that case, I might word it something like "I wouldn't **that you** delude yourself ..." (which makes the sentence rather awkward, and maybe that's why the phrase *that you*  was dropped.) See, "*Oh, I would that I could change his mind.*" ODO http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/would

Comment: The normal US phrasing would be "...but don't delude yourself into thinking...".  You are correct that combining "I" and "yourself" is semantically wrong, since "I" does not control "yourself".  "I" (sometimes) control "myself", and "you" are, of course, the epitome of self-control.

Comment: A perfectly normal phrasing would be *"I wouldn't delude myself into thinking"* (where *"if I were you"* is implicit). Changing the *"myself"* into *"yourself"* is unusual, and arguably ungrammatical, but people have started saying it recently. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+would+not+concern+myself%2C+I+would+not+concern+yourself&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20would%20not%20concern%20myself%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20would%20not%20concern%20yourself%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor: Thanks for the ngram. It's disappointing, though. First the'y stop saying 'if i were you', now they mess up the grammar too. I hate the 'I wouldn't...' sentences.

Comment: @Tushar: I don't think there's anything wrong with leaving out *"if I were you"*. (I won't comment on messing up the grammar.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I wouldn't delude yourself..."* is awkward, at best. Although the meaning would be understood, it is incorrect as it stands. It would be correct to say:

**"Don't delude yourself..."**

-or- (as you surmised)

**"I wouldn't delude** ***myself*** **; if I were you.**

Comment: Thanks. Good to have it confirmed by a native speaker. The line was Malcolm Merlyn's, and the writers usually make him speak excellent English. That's why I got confused.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion

*If I were you, **I** wouldn't delude **myself** into thinking ... ?*

is indeed the canonical form, but the author engages in a clever grammatical play: accentuating the difference between the two persons by using **yourself** instead of "myself". He **manages somehow to speak in the 2nd person** (which is always a feat in narration), while **by keeping "I" in proximity he shows the distinctiveness between them**.

Quite original too, as I didn't find:

"wouldn't delude yourself into"

except in these two places, **only the 2nd of which performs the trick of using both "I" and "myself" in proximity:**

> Victim of Love - Page 74 Dyan Sheldon - 1984
>
> At least **if they moved** around on wheels and went "billup billup
>   billup" **you wouldn't even try** to have serious conversations with
>   them, **wouldn't delude yourself** into believing that you could
>   attempt reason and logic with them, entertain hopes ...
>
> _
>
> STAR WARS: The Old Republic - Advanced Prototype w/ Ion (PvP) - 8/31/2
>   www.swtor.com › ... › English › Classes › Vanguard / Powertech Jan 16,
>   2012
>
> Because Powertech rules **you can still be successful** but **I would
>   not delude yourself** into thinking this is a good build.

Comment: So is Arrow right or is Star Wars wrong too?

Comment: This is not about being right. This is creative, flexible grammar, understandable to me and I'm sure to others too, that plays with characters moving in and out of their shells, __to inhabit the other and to experience his/her point of view__. I feel that both Arrow and Star Wars are of the same understanding.